# How do you change the default customizer section title(s) in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to change the default title of the "Site Identity" tab in the WordPress customizer to a custom value, "Name & Logo" for instance. I've found a number of articles on working with the customizer to add additional options, but that's not what I'm looking for - I just need to change the default section title(s).

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using get_section

```
$wp_customize->get_section('title_tagline')->title = __( 'Name & Logo' );
```

Here is an article that covers changing defaults http://natko.com/changing-default-wordpress-theme-customization-api-sections/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the default one and add new wp customizer. I hope you already know how to add new customizer. To remove default title use something like this $wp_customize->remove_control('controlName');

I hope this will help you out

Comment: I was hoping to avoid removing the default customizer section for Site Identity. I'd like to keep all of the settings, so I don't think removing it would be the best approach. I'd end up re-creating the default fields / settings just to change the section title - I just feel like "Site Identity" isn't the most intuitive name for a non-dev site admin / moderator. Thanks for the info man!